# Are these 2 lines of Shiva Geeta still valid in the Kali Yuga?

Tags: shiva, kali-yuga, curse, shiva-gita

Shiva Geeta Chapter 1, verses 9, 10, 11 and 12:

> नित्याग्निहोत्रिणो विप्राः संति ये गृहमेधिनः
> त एव सर्वफलदाः सुराणां कामधेनवः [9]
> भक्ष्यं भोज्यं च पेयं च यद्यदिष्टं सुपर्वणाम
> अग्नौ हुतेन हविषा सत्सर्वं लभ्यते दिवि [10]
> नान्यदस्ति सुरेशानामिष्टसिद्धिप्रदं दिवि
> दोग्ध्री धेनुर्यथा नीता दुःखदा गृहमेधिनाम [11]
> तथैव ज्ञआनवान्विप्रो देवानां दुःखदो भवेत
> त्रिदशास्तेन विघ्नन्ति प्रविष्टा विषयं नृणाम [12]

---

Meaning:

> In this world, the Brahmin who is a householder (gruhastha), doing Homams and Yagyams by dedicating food and beverages to Gods through fire; such Brahmins are like Kamadhenu to the Demi-Gods because from their Yagyas and Havans the Gods get their food. The Gods accept these offerings with pleasant heart and happiness. (In turn Gods maintain timely rains and help the earth produce grains properly). So, it's a duty of Brahmins to regularly do the homams and yagyams and keep the Gods happy (to get food on earth in return). If Brahmins leave doing these fundamental duties to Gods and immerse themselves in Yoga and in learning about the absolute Brahman (Supreme Lord) and attain pleasure in serving him through the path of knowledge/bhakti, it makes Gods unhappy since they wouldn't get their share of food through sacrifices.For that reason they may become unhappy and may curse. If someone else steals the milk giving cow and takes in a different direction the way its actual owner would feel uncomfortable and would want to get it back, same way these demi-gods also feel uncomfortable when some Brahmin deviates away from his path of normal duties towards the path of Salvation, and in order to get him back for their happiness they try to create disturbances in all possible ways on the devotee's path towards salvation.

However, in the kali yuga, most people anyway do not do stuff mentioned in the scriptures like `sacrifices` or `hom`s everyday. So, are these lines valid even in the Kali Yuga?